# How to mock react component for only one test with jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

I need to mock component only for one test. So I require actual component for every test but in a specific I'm trying to return mocked value. But in such way I'm getting

```
TypeError: specificMockImpl.apply is not a function
```

How can I fix this?

`App.js`

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Test from './Test';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <Test onClick={() => console.log('TEST')}/>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`Test.js`

```
import React from "react";

const Test = ({ onClick }) => (<div>
        Test
   <button onClick={onClick}>BTN</button>
    </div>);

export default Test;
```

Test file

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';
import Test from './Test';

jest.mock('./Test');

beforeEach(() => {
  Test.mockImplementation(jest.requireActual('./Test'))
})

test('should render test component', () => {
  const { getByText} = render(<App />);

  expect(getByText('Test')).toBeInTheDocument()
})

test('should render with mocked test component', () => {
  Test.mockImplementation(() => <div>TEST VALUE</div>)

  const { getByText} = render(<App />);

  expect(getByText('TEST VALUE')).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

Comment: Which line throws this error? show the full error stack

Comment: Maybe you need to use .default. here   Test.mockImplementation(jest.requireActual('./Test').default)